# DJS V14 - Pulling data from json based on given arguments

Tags: discord.js

So I want to make a command that gives the relevant information about the "choice"/"args" that I provide, for example: `/product item:"eggs"` would provide the "name", "price" and "stock" of the item called "eggs", I tried to use a for loop and return the results to the console which it would only return the information for every item. How would I go about only getting it to display the one I choose?

```json
{
 "stockItems": [
    {
      "name": "eggs",
      "price": 50,
      "stock": 100,
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "bacon",
      "price": 70,
      "stock": 10,
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "milk",
      "price": 20,
      "stock": 250,
      "number": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require("discord.js");
const { productInfo } = require("stock.json")

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("product")
    .setDescription("provides information about different products!")
    .addStringOption(option => 
                  option
                    .setName("product")
                    .setDescription("Type the product you want to view!"),
  async execute(interaction) {

let choice = interaction.options.getString("product")

for (let item of productInfo) {
 let stockInfo = `Name: ${item.name} Price: ${item.price} Stock: ${item.stock}`
                    
 if (item.number < 4) {
   console.log(stockInfo)
 }
}
```

The console would log it as this:

```
Name: eggs Price: 50 Stock: 100
Name: bacon Price: 70 Stock: 10
Name: milk Price: 20 Stock: 250
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing you really need to do is to add an if statement in the for loop that checks if your input matches with any of the items.

```
for (let item of productInfo) {
 if (item.name === choice.toLowerCase()) {
  let stockInfo = `Name: ${item.name} Price: ${item.price} Stock: ${item.stock}`
  console.log(stockInfo);                    
  return;
 }
}
```

I also made choice lower case in the if statement incase a user inputs a capitalized word, always a good practice.